# Is a asp.net master page with child pages a SPA?

Tags: asp.net

When I build a asp.net page and have a master page and 6 under pages from this master page - is this a SPA or in fact, it isnt a SPA?

Comment: It *can* be, depending on how these things behave client-side.  How code is separated and organized server-side doesn't *really* make a difference in an SPA, as long as client-side code knows where/how to access the information it needs.  Indeed, keeping these as separate "pages" could make for easier graceful degradation from an SPA to a non-SPA in the event that JavaScript is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

No. The entire point of an SPA is that the browser doesn't have to refresh entirely on every new page.

SPA's use AJAX and similar technology to update parts of the web page, not the entire page.

Answer (score 3):

Since "no" is already taken, I'll take the "maybe." This might be a collection of 6 single pages applications.

Does it rely on some form of AJAX instead of form posting or HTTP GET? (i.e. no postbacks, no requests for a full page except the initial load) (Yes means SPA)

Does it rely primarily on client side templating, usually by fetching JSON and using one of a million different methods to merge that data into the DOM?(Yes means SPA)

Is the bulk of the logic in JavaScript and service files, like asmx, .svc? (or at worst PageMethods?)(Yes means SPA)

Are your aspx pages strangely devoid of control event handers (in fact, w/o anything at all outside of some initial set up in Page_Load?)(Yes means SPA)

Is it not even WebForms and is MVC (which is SPA friendlier, but not really SPA targeting)

Do you often think that it would be easier to dispense with asmx and use a plain .html file? (SPAs generally don't benefit much from the server doing the initial draw of the screen because the vast majority of DOM manipulation there after will be done client side) (Yes means SPA)